# Unity / HoloLens color separation on determined angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I have a problem using HoloLens and Unity 2017.3.0f3. I open a menu (Canvas in World Space) depending on where the user is looking at using the voice commands. 
When menu appears it seems stable, but when walking around it, there is a strange point where it starts to shake and it's separated in different colors, like a rainbow. Very shocking. After 2 seconds it stabilize and appears nice, but everytime I return to that point the same thing happens.

It's quite strange as it just only happen when getting into a specific angle like 65º by left (clockwise direction thinking you are at 6 and the object is the center of the circle).

I have improved the general stabilization using `SetFocusPointForFrame` but anyway it still makes that strange color shake. Also, I tried to reduce FPS to 24 with no results. Quality is set to lowest... I don't know what more I can do. Any help?

To understand better the effect I found this video:

https://youtu.be/QMrx-BU4Hnc?t=6m25s

That final effect is what happens to my hologram, but the color separation is bigger and everything shakes.

Thank you!

EDIT:  I tried to record a video using Device Portal but the objects dissapear instead of shaking O_o really weird.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Hololens as opposed to Vive, but... Are you possibly losing tracking? Are there any other objects in your scene and do they suffer the same effect in the same location? (or same relative location?)

Comment: You could look into the console whether a specific event is happening. Maybe it is not 65 degrees but full rotation and some calculation are required. Dunno but maybe the console will tell there is a major happening.

Comment: @Basic well, the wireframe of the space also shakes, I think the camera is the one that is been shaken because everything moves suddenly.

Comment: @Everts console shows nothing... It's seems that is a bug in the behaviour... But my code does nothing so... dunno

Comment: Try maybe recalibrate the device. Shooting in the dark...

Comment: @Everts yeah will try sure. Anyway it seems that maybe the Unity canvas has some conflicts... I'm going to try to remove the canvas and redo it with 3d elements and see what happens.

Comment: OK, i calibrated it and nothing happens. Also, tried to remove the Canvas and showed cubes and it's the same... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Scraping the barrel... Do other HoloLens programs work when you're in the same physical position? Just trying to rule out something environmental that happens to interfere with the positional tracking.

Comment: Color separation happens when the objects are moving quickly on the screen (you can get the same effect in the shell by turning your head quickly) because the Red, Green, and Blue channels are all separate screens and draw sequentially. I haven't done an app that *requires* the user to walk around, so I'm not sure what might be causing that jitter.

Comment: @Basic yes, every other applications seem to work.

Comment: @Draco18s yes, I know that effect. But this happens even moving too slow, and when arriving to the point it starts to shake hardly. I tried to record a video using Device Portal but the objects dissapear instead of shaking O_o really weird.

Comment: FYI I have exactly the same issue on 2017.2.1f1 VS2017, using the Academy examples.  It seems to happen most when using spatial anchors, but I can't be sure.  Only happens in my own built apps.  Will try your answer below.

Comment: @Jethro It's good to know that it's not an exclusive bug for us haha. Try it and tell me later if it works :) For us it is working much better with that stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not really a fix. But if I use **Unity 2017.1.0f** and **Visual Studio 2015** with **UWP SDK 10.0.14393.0** the problem disappears... I'll try to find if it's a Unity problem or a SDK problem, but for the moment this is a valid solution to avoid the terrible shake with color separation.

Hope this helps someone! :)